# Não consigo alinhar o <thead> com o <tbody> na minha tabela com consulta SQL

Tags: html, css, posicionamento, html-tags

Tenho a seguinte cabeçalho da tabela:

```
<?php
    echo ' <div style="height:65px"> </div>
    <table id="oie" border="1" class="minha-table"> 
        <thead class="headerr" style="position:fixed;">
            <tr style="">
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Ref. Geral</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Nivel</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Numero item</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Material</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Descrição</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Unidade</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Modificação</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Qtd. Eng.</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Qtd. Falt.</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Observação</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LOCALIZADOR_2_V2</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">PDF PT</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">PDF IT</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK JT</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK DXF</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK RAR</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK ZIP</td>
            <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK EPJ</td>
        </thead>
    </tr>';
```

E esse é o body da tabela:

```
while($fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($output))
{
    //echo '<table id="oie" border="1" class="minha-table">';
    echo '<tbody> <tr style="background:'.$fetch['cordefundo'].'; text-color:'.$fetch['cordetexto'].'">';
    echo '<form id="teste" action="banco.php" method="post"><td><input  id="bike'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'" name="bike'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'" onchange="this.form.submit()"  type="checkbox" value="on" '.$fetch['checkbox'].' class="confirmacoes"><a href="banco.php"> </a></td><form>';
    echo '<td >'.utf8_encode($fetch['referenciageral']).'</td>';
    // echo '<td >'.utf8_encode($fetch['formatacao']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['nivel']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['numero_item']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['material']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['descricao']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['unidade']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['modificacao']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['qtdeng']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['qtdfalt']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['OBSERVACAO']).'</td>';

    echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['PDF_PT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_PDF_PT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['PDF_IT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_PDF_IT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_JT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_JT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_DXF'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_DXF_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_RAR'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_RAR_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_ZIP'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_ZIP_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
    echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_EPJ'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_EPJ_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
};
echo '</tr>';
echo ' </tbody> </table> ';
```

O problema é que a barra do thead fica fixa como definido na position mas o nome das colunas não ficam alinhadas com as colunas.
Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Seria mais interessante você apresentar um exemplo do html renderizado em sua pergunta... Seria mais prático para identificar e apresentar uma solução para o erro.

Comment: Copia o código html que renderiza na página, e coloca o seu CSS completo na pergunta tb, só assim não da para simular o seu problema para poder te dar uma resposta.

Comment: Ja tentou conferir as aberturas e fechamentos das tags da tabela? Tem algumas coisas meio perdidas aí no meio...

Comment: html está dentro do php...

Comment: sim Darlei. As tags foram todas abertas e fechadas

Comment: Mas na ordem correta? Veja as duas linhas finais do primeiro trecho de codigo que nos disponibilizou, note que estao invertidas...

Comment: Darlei alterei essas duas ultimas linhas e o erro persiste

Comment: Darlei, uma observação se eu tiro a barra fixa ele alinha mas a barra nao fica fixa claro

Answer (score 0):

São alguns erros pequenos de formatação e ordem de abertura e fechamento das tags...Tente o seguinte:

```
<?php
    echo ' <div style="height:65px"> </div>
    <table id="oie" border="1" class="minha-table"> 
        <thead class="headerr" style="position:fixed;">
            <tr style="">
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Ref. Geral</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Nivel</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Numero item</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Material</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Descrição</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Unidade</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Modificação</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Qtd. Eng.</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Qtd. Falt.</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">Observação</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LOCALIZADOR_2_V2</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">PDF PT</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">PDF IT</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK JT</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK DXF</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK RAR</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK ZIP</td>
                <td style="positon:sticky; top:0;">LINK EPJ</td>
            </tr>
    </thead>';

    while($fetch = sqlsrv_fetch_array($output)){
        //echo '<table id="oie" border="1" class="minha-table">';
        echo '<tbody> 
                <tr style="background:'.$fetch['cordefundo'].'; text-color:'.$fetch['cordetexto'].'">';
        echo '<td>
                <form id="teste" action="banco.php" method="post">
                    <input  id="bike'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'" name="bike'.$fetch['referenciageral'].'" onchange="this.form.submit()"  type="checkbox" value="on" '.$fetch['checkbox'].' class="confirmacoes">
                    <a href="banco.php"> </a>
                </form>
              </td>';
        echo '<td >'.utf8_encode($fetch['referenciageral']).'</td>';
        // echo '<td >'.utf8_encode($fetch['formatacao']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['nivel']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['numero_item']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['material']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['descricao']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['unidade']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['modificacao']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['qtdeng']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['qtdfalt']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.utf8_encode($fetch['OBSERVACAO']).'</td>';

        echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['PDF_PT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_PDF_PT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
        echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['PDF_IT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_PDF_IT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
        echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_JT'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_JT_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
        echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_DXF'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_DXF_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
        echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_RAR'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_RAR_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
        echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_ZIP'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_ZIP_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
        echo '<td><a id="logo-container" href="'.$fetch['LINK_EPJ'].'" class="brand-logo"><img src="'.$fetch['LINK_TCD#LINK_EPJ_IMAGE'].'"  /></a></td>';
};
echo '</tr>';
echo ' </tbody> </table> ';
```

`Position Fixed` pode bugar a tabela dependendo do resto do layout, em todo caso teste sem ele.

Comment: Darlei sem ele funciona... mas preciso saber como deixar o thead fixo daí! Alguma solução?

Comment: position fixed nao esta funcionando?